# How can I merge two protected branches in git when they are not in sync?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

I have a GitLab repository for my application. Following some guidelines (https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) I created a "main" branch that mirrors the production version and a "develop" branch that mirrors the version currently under acceptance test. After finishing the acceptance test, the develop version is rolled out and will be merged into main.

All worked fine until recently we had to ship an emergency change. For this, I created a branch off main, committed the changes and merged them back to main.

Now we have the next scheduled release ready on develop, so I created a merge request from develop to main. This merge request tells me that develop is 2 commits behind main (which isttrue due to the emergency branch). So I create a merge request from main to develop. Now this one is also behind develop (which is true due to the regular functional updates in this release).

In the emergency change we changed a file that should not be changed in the developmen branch (a quickfix, that we solved otherwise in the main release).

Now I cannot merge develop into main because I have to dvance develop to the main head, but I cannot do this because I would have to commit the "main" changes (or their override) into develop which is protected.

Creating a new branch to incorporate the main changes into a merge request to develop did not work.

What is the correct way to move develop to the head of main while not being able to directly commit to develop (or main)?

Comment: It sounds like the problem is that you have setup your repo so that it only accepts MRs if the source branch is _up to date_ with the target branch.... rebasing long running branches is not a good idea and then creating a branch just to do the merge and then set that in an MR sounds like an overkill (though not that complex, which is a plus).... perhaps you should either disable that flag for a little bit so you can do this merge between the branches _or_ find a way to avoid it for that MR (if possible).

Comment: about that hotfix on main: do you need to completely ignore it, and just take the code from the tip of the `develop` branch ? or do you need to keep some parts of that hotfix ?

Comment: The hotfix can be ignored completely; this is our general policy for hotfixing, so a solution that ignores advances on the main branch is acceptable for me

Comment: @eftshift0: this flag could help - where do I find it?

Comment: In your repo hosting provider.... the problem you are describing is _not_ a git problem.

Comment: @eftshift0 Requiring `develop` be up to date with `main` before merging into `main` doesn't require a rebase; a merge will suffice.

Comment: It's a catch 22.... if I understood it correctly, if you create an MR to merge `main` into `develop`, guess what you will get.

Comment: @eftshift0 but that setting should only be one-way. Merges into `main` require it, but not the other way around.

Comment: Agreed it should be like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a setting which forces an incoming branch to be fully up to date with `main` before merging into `main`. This is fine to help prevent the scenario you *almost* found yourself in, which is when you have a `hotfix`, and you don't merge those changes back into `develop`, and then the next time you deploy to production from `develop` you blow away the changes in the `hotfix`.

If you are using that setting, you only need it enabled for merges into `main`. You  don't need to have that setting enabled for merges into `develop`, though there is a workaround for that if you wish to leave it on for `develop` as well.

Normally, after merging a `hotfix` into `main`, you should immediately then merge `main` into `develop`.<sup>1</sup> Since `develop` is a protected branch in GitLab, this might simply mean creating a Merge Request from `main` into `develop`. In some cases you cannot create a MR directly from `main` into `develop`, and instead need to use an in-between temporary branch, for example if:

1. There are conflicts when merging `main` into `develop`.
2. There are not conflicts, but there is at least one change that you don't wish to be applied to the `develop` branch.
3. You have enabled the flag on `develop` that all incoming merges must be up to date with `develop`.

Regardless of which of the above reasons for the exception, the solution to creating the in-between branch is the same (these commands assume your remote name is `origin`):

```
# get the latest code
git fetch

# create a new temporary branch starting from the latest develop
git switch -c merge-main-into-develop origin/develop --no-track

# Merge in main
git merge origin/main
# resolve conflicts if needed and continue to complete the merge

# push out your branch and set it to track the new branch
git push -u
```

Now you can create a PR from `merge-main-into-develop` into `develop`.

If you happen to be in exception scenario #2 above, where you don't wish to actually bring all of the hotfix changes from `main` into `develop`, you have a few options:

1. If you want some files but not all, you could change the merge command to be `git merge origin/main --no-commit`. This will pause the merge with the files saved, and you can modify the index however you need to before committing. You might choose this option if you have some version files that were modified on `main` that you don't wish to update on `develop`. Consider updating the merge commit message to explain what you are changing and why.
2. If you don't want any of the changes from the hotfix to be brought into `develop`, perhaps because you already fixed the same thing in a different and preferred way on `develop`, you could use the merge strategy "ours, by modifying the merge command to be: `git merge origin/main -s ours`. This will bring in the commits but without any of the changes. Consider updating the merge commit message to explain why you are doing this.
3. A similar method to number 2 is to accept the merge as is, but then revert the merge with a commit message explaining why. This has the same effect as #2, but creates one additional commit. The advantage of this method is it's easier to predict what happened simply by glancing at the commit message titles.

Ultimately, the key idea here is you need all of the commit IDs that are on `main` to be present on `develop` before merging `develop` back into `main`.

---

<sup>1</sup> The Git Flow documentation suggest merging `hotfix` into `main` and then also merging `hotfix` into `develop`. That will produce the same *state* but will not contain the new merge commit created on `main` (which is recommended). By merging `main` into `develop` instead you bring that new merge commit over as well and will therefore keep `develop` up to date with `main`. Note this also means you'll need to merge `main` into `develop` right after merging `develop` into `main`, just to bring over that merge commit!